# Which field type to store latitude and longitude MYSQL with heighst accuracy?

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-maps, location

I am getting locations as "latitude" & "longitude" separated and I need to store them in a MYSQL database.

I've looked around to see what's the best data type to store these info with, and the best I found was

```
latitude decimal(9,6) signed,
longitude decimal(9,6) signed
```

But I am aware that at many times I'll be getting more precise and more accurate locations, so I need to know what's the field type that I should use to get the potential maximum accuracy when storing the data.

I'm not sure if the best thing to do here is just to use a varchar or do something else.
This data will/might be used in the future to suggest nearby locations, send precise-location-based notifications and also interacting with maps & show nearby users.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be queried, I would suggest just a plain-old varchar should do. That you can store as many chars as you need without loosing the accuracy. Or else, you should state your use case here since this is pretty opinion based without knowing your use case. Please revise your question a little bit :)

Comment: @LionelChan I'm so sorry, I should've done that of course. I have edited the question :)

Comment: You could have your `decimal(9,6)` for query purpose, and `varchar` for precision need in one row of data